# Site Hacked, No Original Email

Tags: security, admin

I have a slight issue.. Actually a major one!

The site I am working on is built in expression engine and it was hacked and whoever has done it has changed the password and the client has no idea what the original email is when the site was first built.

Is there any way at all I can get into the backend of the website?

Hoping someone can help!

Thanks!

Comment: Don't actually tell this guy how to take control of an EECMS website !

Comment: @emmanuel Unless one has access to the database, there's no way to do this, and if one does has access to the database, we can only assume it's legitimate access.

Answer (score 11):

Do you have access to the `MySQL` database? If so, you can change the admin's email and initiate a password reset at the login screen.